# How to set <aui:button> icon in Liferay without using Javascript?

Tags: liferay, portlet, alloy-ui, liferay-aui

I'm trying to set icon to `<aui:button>` like on this [tutorial](http://www.liferay.com/pt/community/liferay-projects/alloy-ui/demo?title=community-liferay-projects-alloy-ui-demos-button). 
But solution described there doesn't work well in my case, because I have a table and on each row I have a button with different resourceUrl. Like this:

```
<portlet:resourceURL id="saveReport" var="saveReportURL">
   <portlet:param name="reportId" value="${report.reportId}" />
</portlet:resourceURL>

<aui:button onclick="location.href = '${saveReportURL}'">
```

Is it possible to set icon in `<aui:button>` without using JavaScript as described in tutorial?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can write this below code for setting icon in liferay alloy button

```
<aui:button type="cancel" cssClass="btn-info" icon="icon-upload-alt" iconAlign="right" value="upload" />
```

> you need to use the **icon** attribute for this setting "**Icon glyphs**"
>   
>   you need to use **cssClass** for adding extra design button class for the designing
>   
>   you need to set **iconAlign** attribute for left or right side of the button text value

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add an icon to a button without using JavaScript by adding one of these [`Icon`](http://liferay.github.io/alloy-bootstrap/base-css.html#icons) CSS classes to your button. For example, if you wanted to create a button with a calendar icon, your code should look something like this:

```
<aui:button class="icon-calendar" ... />
```